# Procedural dungeon generator - Coroutines or Async await

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm building a dungeon generator script that uses a list of pre-made rooms and connects them together at random. Its a 3D project and I'm not using a grid layout, since i don't want the environment to feel repetitive.
The way it works is that once a room is put in place, at a randomly selected exit door it tries to place another room (room02), uses an overlap box the size of room02, if it fits it leaves it if not it deletes it and tries a different room. And this process is repeated for as long as I want the dungeon to be.

But for the collision check to work I need to wait a frame between instances and for that I've been using Coroutines, but they can get messy if i want to keep track of when each of them is done running.
So I tried looking into Asyncronous functions and Tasks but the issue is that those, from what I could find, are not super relyable when traying to wait for individual frames.

How would you guys recommend I approach this script?
I'll attach the script just in case you're curious but its long and a bit messy.
Thank you!

Here's the script

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics.Tracing;
using System.Linq;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using Random = UnityEngine.Random;
using UnityEditor.MemoryProfiler;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;

public class HouseGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int roomsToGoal = 4;
    public float spaceBetweenRooms = 0.2f;
    public int maxBranchLength;

    public List<GameObject> roomPrefabs = new List<GameObject>();
    public Stack<Room> SceneRoomsStack = new Stack<Room>();
    private List<Connection> mainConnectionList = new List<Connection>();
    private List<Room> lastRoomsList = new List<Room>();

    public GameObject startingRoom;
    public GameObject connectionPrefab;

    private int lastID;

    void Start()
    {
        StartRoomSpawn();

        StartCoroutine(SpawnRooms());
        
    }


    IEnumerator SpawnRooms()
    {
        int maxLoop = 100;
        for (int i = 0; i < roomsToGoal; i++)
        {
            bool roomPlaced = PlaceRoomBool(mainConnectionList[mainConnectionList.Count-1], mainConnectionList, true);
            //this if makes is so the loop isnt counted if no room is created.
            if (!roomPlaced && maxLoop > 0)
                i--;
            //safeguard so the program doesn't ever loop to infinity
            maxLoop--;
            // we need a frame between loops to give collisions time to work.
            yield return null;
        }
        mainConnectionList[mainConnectionList.Count - 1].ShowDoor();
        Room lastRoom = mainConnectionList[mainConnectionList.Count - 1].GetComponentInChildren<Room>();
        lastRoomsList.Add(lastRoom);
        Debug.Log(mainConnectionList[mainConnectionList.Count - 1].transform.parent.name + "'s door was closed because it was the last door in the main branch.");

        yield return null;

        //Main branch is done, now we start constructing the branches.

        Debug.Log(SceneRoomsStack.Count);
        yield return StartCoroutine(LookForFreeDoors());
        Debug.Log(SceneRoomsStack.Count);

        SelectSafeRoom();
        Actions.OnFinishLoading?.Invoke();

    }

    IEnumerator LookForFreeDoors()
    {
        Queue<Connection> newBranches = new Queue<Connection>();
        int count = SceneRoomsStack.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            Room room = SceneRoomsStack.Pop();
            foreach(Connection connection in room.connectionPoints)
            {
                //Debug.Log("Pop" + room.name + " connection " + connection.name + " " + connection.openConnection);
                if(connection.isFree == true)
                {
                    newBranches.Enqueue(connection);
                    connection.isFree = false;
                }
            }
        }

        
        int branchNumber = newBranches.Count;
        for(int i = 0; i < branchNumber; i++)
        {
            //in newBranches queue we store all the free connections in the main branch, from which
            //we spawn new branches.
            //branchConnections is a list that we use to find the last room in the branch and close its
            //doors.
            List<Connection> branchConnections = new List<Connection>();
            branchConnections.Add(newBranches.Dequeue());
            for (int j = 0; j < maxBranchLength; j++)
            {
                yield return null;
                Room room = PlaceRoom(branchConnections[branchConnections.Count - 1], branchConnections, false);
                branchConnections[branchConnections.Count - 1].isFree = false;
                if(room == null)
                {
                    //throw new Exception("Room not found");
                }
                if (j == maxBranchLength - 1)

                    //room.ShowExitKey();
                    lastRoomsList.Add(room);
            }
            //Null check
            if (branchConnections[branchConnections.Count - 1] != null)
                branchConnections[branchConnections.Count - 1].ShowDoor();
            Debug.Log(branchConnections[branchConnections.Count - 1].transform.parent.name + "'s door was closed because it was the last door in the branch.");


        }

        GameObject[] finalConnectionList = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Connection");
        foreach (GameObject connection in finalConnectionList)
        {
            var component = connection.GetComponent<Connection>();
            if (component.isFree)
            {
                component.ShowDoor();
                Debug.Log(component.transform.parent.name + "'s door was closed because it was open to the void.");

            }
        }

    }
    //We spawn the starting Room and set one of its connections as the lasConnection
    void StartRoomSpawn()
    {
        var room = Instantiate(startingRoom).GetComponent<Room>();

        //we close all connections first
        foreach(Connection connection in room.connectionPoints)
        {
            connection.openConnection = false;
            connection.isFree = false;
        }
        var selectedInConnection = SelectRandomConnection(room);
        //now we open just the one we selected.
        selectedInConnection.openConnection = true;
        selectedInConnection.isFree = false;
        selectedInConnection.ShowFrame();
        //We add the out connection to the main branch's connection list
        mainConnectionList.Add(selectedInConnection);


        SceneRoomsStack.Push(room);

        foreach(Connection connection in room.connectionPoints)
        {
            if (!connection.openConnection)
            {
                connection.ShowDoor();
                Debug.Log(connection.transform.parent.name + "'s door was closed because it wasn't the chosen opening in the first room");
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    void SelectSafeRoom()
    {
        Room[] roomList = FindObjectsOfType<Room>();

        int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, roomList.Length);

        if (roomList[randomIndex].roomType != RoomType.Corridor ||
            roomList[randomIndex].roomType != RoomType.Stairs)
        {
            int maxLoops = 50;
            while ((roomList[randomIndex].roomType == RoomType.Corridor ||
                roomList[randomIndex].roomType == RoomType.Stairs) &&
                maxLoops > 0)
            {
                randomIndex = Random.Range(0, roomList.Length);
                maxLoops--;
            }
        }
        roomList[randomIndex].isSafeRoom = true;
        roomList[randomIndex].TurnOnLights();

    }

    bool PlaceRoomBool(Connection outConnection, List<Connection> connectionList, bool isMainBranch)
    {
        //This does the same as PlaceRoom but we make it so it returns a boolean instead.

        Room room = PlaceRoom(outConnection, connectionList, isMainBranch);

        if (room == null)
            return false;
        else
            return true;

    }
    Room PlaceRoom(Connection outConnection, List<Connection> connectionList, bool isMainBranch)
    {
        //return true if was able to create a room, false if not
        //
        Connection anchor = CreateRoom(outConnection);
        var room = anchor.GetComponentInChildren<Room>();
        //Debugging
        
        if (room == null)
            throw new Exception(anchor.name + " did not create a room");


        room.name = room.name + Time.deltaTime;
        anchor.name = anchor.name + Time.deltaTime;
        anchor.isFree = false;
        anchor.ShowFrame();

        //yield return null waits until the next frame so collisions can be calculated.
        //yield return null;
        //now we call CheckColliders to get the number of collisions with room.
        Collider[] colliders = CheckCollider(room);

        Debug.Log(colliders.Length);
        if(colliders.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach(Collider collider in colliders)
            {                
                //there was an exception being thrown here where a collider without a room component
                //like a card in it was caught in the check, so it was not able to find said room component
                //Debug.Log(collider.name);
                if(collider.transform.parent != null
                   && collider.transform.parent.GetComponent<Room>().ID != room.ID)
                {
                    Destroy(anchor.gameObject);
                    return null;
                    
                }
            }

        }
        
        var selectedExit = SelectRandomConnection(room);
        selectedExit.name = selectedExit.name + Time.deltaTime;

        int counter = 0;
        if (selectedExit.isEntrance == true)
        {
            while(selectedExit.isEntrance == true && counter < 100)
            {
                selectedExit = SelectRandomConnection(room);
            }
        }
        selectedExit.openConnection = false;
        selectedExit.isFree = false;
        connectionList.Add(selectedExit);

        //we stack only if we're spawning in the main branch.
        if (isMainBranch)
        {
            SceneRoomsStack.Push(room);
            room.isMainBranch = true;
        }

        return room;
    }

    Collider[] CheckCollider(Room room)
    {
        //now we get the collider's extent, and get its world coordinates, to get the angle right.
        Vector3 worldExtent = room.childRenderer.bounds.extents;
        //the overlap boc for some reason spawns halfway down the object's y size. 
        //here we forve-correct that behavior.
        Collider[] colliders = Physics.OverlapBox(room.transform.position + new Vector3(0, worldExtent.y, 0), worldExtent);

        //debugging
        GameObject debugCube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
        debugCube.transform.position = room.transform.position + new Vector3(0, worldExtent.y, 0);
        debugCube.transform.localScale = worldExtent * 2;
        debugCube.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;
        debugCube.transform.SetParent(room.transform);
        debugCube.SetActive(false);
        debugCube.name = "Debugging Cube";
        //debugging

        return colliders;
    }

    //This spawns a new room and sets one of its connectors to lastConnection;
    Connection CreateRoom(Connection outConnection)
    {
        var room = Instantiate(roomPrefabs[Random.Range(0, roomPrefabs.Count)]);
        room.GetComponent<Room>().ID = lastID;
        lastID++;

        var selectedInConnection = SelectRandomConnection(room.GetComponent<Room>());
        selectedInConnection.isEntrance = true;
        selectedInConnection.openConnection = false;
        selectedInConnection.isFree = false;
        //Here anchor is created and room is parented to it.
        var anchor = SetupRoomAnchor(selectedInConnection, room);

        anchor.transform.position = outConnection.transform.position;
        anchor.transform.rotation = outConnection.transform.rotation;
        //we rotate it so it faces the the outConnection, and move it back to leave space between
        //rooms.
        anchor.transform.Rotate(0, 180, 0);
        anchor.transform.position += anchor.transform.forward * spaceBetweenRooms * -1;

        anchor.name = room.name;

        return anchor.GetComponent<Connection>();
    }

    Connection SelectRandomConnection(Room room)
    {
        int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, room.connectionPoints.Count());
        var selectedConnection = room.connectionPoints[randomIndex].GetComponent<Connection>();
        
        return selectedConnection;
        
    }

    GameObject SetupRoomAnchor(Connection connection, GameObject room)
    {
        //Here we create the anchor and parent the room to it
        var anchor = Instantiate(connectionPrefab);
        anchor.transform.position = connection.transform.position;
        anchor.transform.rotation = connection.transform.rotation;

        room.transform.SetParent(anchor.transform);

        return anchor;
    }

    
}
```

Comment: choice is arguably yours

Comment: I'd recommend [UniTask](https://github.com/Cysharp/UniTask) .. Coroutines are also fine but quite Unity specific .. using UniTask you can stick to the more common `async - await` patterns and apply your learnings to any other c#/.Net environment

Comment: Btw `// we need a frame between loops to give collisions time to work.` not if you force a physics update via [`Physics.Simulate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Simulate.html) .. otherwise if that's the case instead of frames it should probably rather be physics frames and you should use `yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();` instead ...

Comment: Oh awesome I was not aware that I could force physics like that. Thank you!